# What is the purpose of utility layer and how is this linked with other layers in a web application architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, dao, layer, utility

I am new to Java EE architecture (trying to do some reading on this - please suggest good sources).

When we use MVC pattern, the DAO layer consists of classes that contain methods to access the database. Similarly service layer contains classes that make use of methods from DAO classes and have some business logic. I see in some projects that Util classes are used and they contain methods that perform some work for the service layer classes.

What is the exact purpose of this Utility layer? Can it contain getters and setters from Spring dependency injection?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "utility layer". Constructions like like `MyMagnificentMailer` are just a different kind of service. I am not sure if you actually separate the domain objects from DAOs (or other forms of abstraction for storage ), but just like domain object can contain and interact with other domain object, same way your `Authentication` service can interact with `Mailer` and vice versa.

There is not rule saying, that *real* services have to be build on top DAOs.